# Timeout in expect/Bash scripts

Tags: bash, expect

I am using the following program in Bash to automate the connection through SSH to an external host and remotely execute a Python script there.
I have a problem understanding how timeout works in expect scripts.

I want to allow 60 seconds to SSH-connect and let the remote host ask for the password, and then I want to allow 30 minutes (1800 seconds) for the Python script to run and finish its job.

```
user=some_user
host=some_host
password=some_password

expect -c "
          set timeout 60
          spawn ssh -p 5023 -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$host python script.py
          match_max 1024
          expect "*?assword:*"
          send \"$password\r\"
          send \"\r\"
          set timeout 1800
          expect eof"
```

My program is (quite often) failing after 5 minutes (300 seconds), and I can pin it down to the remote Python script.

However, after reading the Expect manual page (https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), I am not sure how to best use the timeout option.

My questions then would be:
- Should I only use "set timeout N" once?
- If yes, should I set the timeout Before, or After the "spawn" line of code?
- If there are several "set timeout N" lines, does any of them override the others?

Comment: Unless someone is forcibly preventing you from using public-key authentication, there is no reason to use `expect` to automate `ssh` logins like this.

Comment: @chepner. Thank you. I know but, as it turns out, I can't execute the remote Python script if I use public-key authentication. It uses a third-party software that I can't modify. I need to use expect.

Comment: Your use of `set timeout` is ok. Changes to it affect following statements. Note: you should probably replace `"` by `\"` in the expect `?assword:` line.

Comment: What uses third-party software? Why does the Python script care how you logged in?

Comment: The "failing after 5 minutes" is your python program. What debugging have you done with it?

Comment: @chepner If I log in using public-key authentication and run the Python script using the third-party Python library, I get the session timeout error. I have asked the provider and they say I have to log on using username+password in order to execute Python scripts using that library.

Comment: @meuh `expect \"*?assword:*\"` works as well, thanks.

Comment: @glennjackman Enough to be sure that the error comes from the external Python library. Anyway, my question was related to the use of `timeout` in `expect` scripts. I wanted to know if I needed to set one `timeout` for the SSH connection and another one for the `python` command, and where to set them. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Perhaps when trying with public-key authentication, you can to use `ssh -t` to force use of a pty at the remote. This make make the python script behave differently if it is checking whether stdin is a tty.

Comment: When the Python script aborts, the ssh session will end and the `expect eof` command will end also. The timeout value is not a factor here